# LESS: how to convert a list of called mixins to a for loop with a unique call

Tags: less, mixins

I crated many mixins to generate different kinds of classes for various purposes. Specifically I have to use a unique colorizer set using the standard bootstrap variable name, such as (only an example):

```
@type-primary: #fff;
@type-success: #f00;
@type-info: #ff0;
@type-default: #000;
@type-warning: #0f0;
@type-danger: #0ff;
```

Actually I created my mixins in the following form, with a "mother" as *prefix* to which I attached various *suffixes*

```
.text
{
  &-primary { .color_text(@type-primary); }
  &-success { .color_text(@type-success); }
  &-info    { .color_text(@type-info); }
  &-default { .color_text(@type-default); }
  &-warning { .color_text(@type-warning); }
  &-danger  { .color_text(@type-danger); }
}
```

After this, I can then create the final called mixin such as (so simple because it's only an example)

```
.color_text (@color)
{
  color:@color;
}
```

I woud like to automate and optimize `.text` mixin to avoid many repeated rows, I think with a for loop. How could be possible?

---

Final results should be (in this case)

```
.text-primary {
  color: #fff;
}
.text-success {
  color: #f00;
}
.text-info {
  color: #ff0;
}
.text-default {
  color: #000;
}
.text-warning {
  color: #0f0;
}
.text-danger {
  color: #0ff;
}
```

---

In **PSEUDO-CODE** something like this could be ideal

```
@type-primary: #fff;
@type-success: #f00;
@type-info: #ff0;

.createContextClass("classNamePrefix",{@type-primary,@type-success,@type-info},mixinToBeCalled);

// Another call could be
.createContextClass("otherClassNamePrefix",{@type-primary,@type-success},otherMixinToBeCalled);
```

where, in relation to my original code, `classNamePrefix` should be the name of first part of final CSS class, then is passed an array with all kind of suffix that I wish in final CSS code, and `mixinToBeCalled` is the mixin that creates all css rules for final `.text-primary`, `.text-success`, `.text-info`.

*For the moment, following **Seven-Phases-Max**' suggestion, I improved his solution in the [following way](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozBkAb)*

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/yaVAEx)?

Comment: @Harry You can add this code as an answer.

Comment: @Harry Hi Harry, something similar but still no so general. I tried, starting from your example, to make an improvement in final direction but I don't know how to save an updated CodePen (is it not like jsFiddle?) to show you

Comment: @LucaDetomi: You should fork my pen and save it.

Comment: @Harry Great!!!! This is [mine version](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGNGmp) (also simpliflied in array length). As you can see, `.underline-` classes are not rendered as expected because is called always `.color_text` mixin. I think that a possible solution coul be passing `@classNamePrefix` as parameter to `for-loop` but surely you are able to complete example and maybe find a better and compact solution. In general, you can assume that I have several classes that must be created with suffix `-primary`, `-success`, ecc. (in this simplified case, only two)

Comment: I don't think what you are looking for can be done with Less because you can't call mixins with dynamic names (here you are looking to call two different mixins). If there are only a few such mixins, you can add a input parameter to the mixin and call the appropriate mixin based on guards.

Comment: Something like [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/yaVAEx) is what I meant by *add a input parameter to the mixin and call the appropriate mixin based on guards*.

Comment: Thanks Harry, I'll try to think better about this and maybe in the near future I'll post an updated, more precise question. I could also simply edit this one, to make it better and clearer

Comment: Why do you need these `.color_text` and `.underline` (and whatever else "content") mixins at all? I'd use just loop and a single "content" thing separated form the loop for readability. [Like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/b386260e7ee33c2522a49622ade832d0).

Comment: @seven-phases-max I understand that is very difficult to find a balance between real case needs and necessary simplified versions that could be posted here as examples. I should post maybe 100 rows of code to show real world example.

Comment: In general, I want to create classes to simply color a text, or others that creates different Buttons (complete with hover/disabled/active pseudo-states), or others one that creates "notifications messages" or badges, etc. always in different colors. In addition, my original implementation (in question) could allows me to create only some color classes for some mixins, simply not adding some `&-XXX { .yyy_zzz(@type-warning); }` mixin calls. So is a bit verbose, but currently flexible. Imagine for example to create only two color classes for `.text-*` ad 3 for `.underline-*`